# Loading array into json, loading array back into program and using it globally with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, database, parsing

so what I want to achieve is loading an array that holds objects into json so that I can parse it back into the program and using it anywhere in my program. I have tried the fs way of doing this but I soon found out that I cannot use the variables outside the async, callback function when I read it. I am asking if there is a better method of loading my array full of objects into json, reading it and being able to use these variables anywhere in my program. I would also like some insight as I would like to learn more about a topic I am a rookie with, thank you!

my problem is that I cannot access variables from an async callback function as it returns undefined when I call it out of the function itself.

```
class Blockchain {
  constructor() {
    this.chain = [Blockchain.getGenesis()];
    console.log(Blockchain.getGenesis());
}
//further into the code with the issued function reading the data from .json to //place the objects into variables for the program to use
  static getGenesis(genChain) {
     fs.readFile(jsonRoute, 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;

    jsonChain = JSON.parse(data);
    genesis = jsonChain.blocks[0].GENESIS_DATA;
    
    //console.log(genesis);
    
    /*console.log(jsonChain.blocks[0].GENESIS_DATA.lastHash); //specify element of where the object is and the field that you want to read*/
    
    /*jsonChain.blocks.push({
        GENESIS_DATA
    });

    console.log(jsonChain);
    
        fs.writeFile('CDSM/CDSM.json', JSON.stringify(jsonChain), 'utf-8', function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Done!');*/
    });
    return genesis; //returns undefined since the variable I need to access gets //destroyed before I call it in the constructor (this is a multi module project //and need the array to "save" basically
}
    
}
```

.json file:

```
{"blocks":[{"GENESIS_DATA":{"timestamp":1,"lastHash":"v01d","hash":"?M=(((Position-1)=>ter)=>sen)=>non?","difficulty":20,"nonce":0,"data":[]}}]}
```

due to this architectural restriction I am asking if there is a different way of reading a json file and referencing the contents of it into variables.

Comment: Are you talking about loading a `.json` file? Where is the original data coming from? Please show some code you have tried.

Comment: loading data into an existing .json that takes an array. If I show you my old code, please do not try to build onto it as I am asking for different architecture or different way of doing it since I cannot access variables in a callback async function using the fs library.

Comment: Sorry, I think you're a little confused on some terminology so it's making it hard for me to understand what you mean. I'm going to try and help you though. Are you saying that you just have an array of objects that you'd like to use in multiple places in your code?

Comment: I am sure that I am mixing up terminology but I have edited the post and it should make more sense now

Comment: Ah, I understand, that helps. I'll write you a solution.

Comment: I appreciate it, if it is possible could you also provide some insight, as I am quite literally a nodejs noobie. Everything is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `getGenesis` is asynchronous, you need to have it return a `Promise`. A promise is basically just a task that will be completed at some point in the future, and it's gonna wait for the result and do something with it.

```
class Blockchain {
  constructor() {
    this.chain = [Blockchain.getGenesis()];
    console.log(Blockchain.getGenesis());
  }
  static getGenesis(genChain) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      fs.readFile(jsonRoute, 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
        if(err) return reject(err);
        const jsonChain = JSON.parse(data);
        resolve(jsonChain.blocks[0].GENESIS_DATA);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
Blockchain.getGenesis(genChain).then(function(genesisData) {
  console.log(genesisData); // Genesis block data is here.
}, function(err) {
  // This only runs if there was an error.
  console.log(err);
});
```

`resolve` and `reject` are simply two functions you can call to tell the promise about the data when it's complete. If the request succeeded then you call `resolve` with the data. If there is an error then you call `reject` with the error data.

The `Promise` class exposes the `then` method, which simply binds a `success` and `error` callback to be executed when the promise is complete.

Comment: You are amazing, thank you for the explanation, it was a pleasure learning from this and it also worked!

Comment: @NoobGuy Glad to help! There's a lot of neat things you can do with Promises so I'd recommend you do some more research on them. They are extremely useful for handling all kinds of asynchronous scenarios.